# Import statement for including Ember logger?

Tags: ember.js

I want to do something like:

```
import { Ember, Logger } from 'ember';
```

And then be able to do:

```
Logger.log("test")
```

But I'm not sure I understand how the imports work. What is the right way to do this so I can use functions in Ember and Logger and not have to do Ember.Logger.log()?

Comment: As of ember 3.2 `Ember.Logger` has been deprecated in favour of using the console directly. You can read more in [this section](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x#toc_ember-console-deprecate-logger) of the deprecation tracker.

Comment: Thanks @PatsyIssa! But when I switch to console I get a warning in the ember server saying "error  Unexpected console statement  no-console". What is the right way to deal with this?

Comment: That is an eslint warning, you can disable it for that line with `// eslint-disable-line no-console`

Comment: The eslint warning is there only to make sure you do not leave around unintended console.log statements that you put in there while debugging. If you really intend for your application to log in production, feel free to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patsy mentioned in their comment, the Ember Logger is indeed deprecated. You can see more details about this deprecation here: https://deprecations-app-prod.herokuapp.com/deprecations/ember/v3.x/#toc_ember-console-deprecate-logger and if you want to learn more about **why** this was deprecated you could read the original RFC and related conversations here: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/297

There is a way that you can have debug logs printed out in development but have them then be stripped in production builds of your app. You can see more information about it here: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/functions/@ember%2Fdebug/debug